# How to install/enable GMP (math functions) for PHP on Ubuntu?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, php, packages

When calling a gmp math function like `gmp_mod`, I get:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function gmp_mod()
```

I have installed the `php5-gmp` package and restarted the web-server, and the function is still undefined. The server is running Ubuntu 10.04 and PHP is running as an Apache module. All software was installed from official packages.

How do I enable the GMP math functions in PHP? I'm looking for a solution that uses official packages, not compiling from source.

Answer (score 27):

Here is the way which worked for me :

1. Installed GMP with `apt-get install php5-gmp`
2. Added `extension=php_gmp.so` to php.ini

Et voilà !

phpinfo() sample :

```
gmp
gmp support     enabled
GMP version     4.3.2
```

It works fine here (Debian), so I suppose it will be ok for Ubuntu too.

Comment: On Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, I needed to use `gmp.so`, not `php_gmp.so`. I also needed to restart Apache for the changes to take effect (not surprising as I'm using `mod_php`).

Comment: In my case `sudo apt-get install php5-gmp` automatically updated php.ini and restarted Apache.

Comment: For php 7 : apt-get install php7.0-gmp

Comment: @Benj Can u please tell me, how to install gmp library for php on mac OS?

Comment: For the record, for PHP7.1 : apt-get install php7.1-gmp